# Set order item meta data before e-mail notifications is sent

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to update the order item meta data after the payment is complete but before the e-mail notifications is sent so the meta data can be displayed in the e-mail.

I am imitating the default function here: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-stock-functions.html#source-view.92 because I need to swap the `wc_reduce_stock_levels` with my own custom `custom_wc_reduce_stock_levels` function.

I use the code below to fire the `custom_wc_reduce_stock_levels` function. In that (quite long) function I update meta data with `$item->update_meta_data('Plukvare', 'Ja');` and `$item->save();`. The meta data is saved correct on the order, and displayed on the thank you page, but it is not displayed in the e-mail notifications. However, if I re-trigger the e-mail notification afterwards, the meta data is displayed correctly.

```
function custom_wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels($order_id){
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    
    if (!$order){
        return;
    }
    
    $stock_reduced = $order->get_data_store()->get_stock_reduced($order_id);
    $trigger_reduce = apply_filters('woocommerce_payment_complete_reduce_order_stock', !$stock_reduced, $order_id);
    
    // Only continue if we're reducing stock.
    if (!$trigger_reduce){
        return;
    }

    // Custom stock reduction logic
    custom_wc_reduce_stock_levels($order);
    
    // Ensure stock is marked as "reduced" in case payment complete or other stock actions are called.
    $order->get_data_store()->set_stock_reduced($order_id, true);
}
//Adds custom handling
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'custom_wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'custom_wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'custom_wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );

//Removes normal handling
remove_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels' );
```